# Only return string after a pattern/keyword

Tags: perl, sed, grep

I have a list (values from an array) which looks like this:

```
order_reply1={order_tag=1286955
order_reply2={order_tag=1286956
order_reply3={order_tag=1286957
order_reply4={order_tag=1286958
order_reply5={order_tag=1286959
order_reply6={order_tag=1286960
order_reply7={order_tag=1286961
```

From this, I want to return the value after order_tag=. How can I go about doing this? I dont want anything before this "keyword". The reason is that I want the returned tags to keep quering a database with these references.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this in Perl, what code have you already tried? And where did you get stuck ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = (
'order_reply1={order_tag=1286955',
'order_reply2={order_tag=1286956',
'order_reply3={order_tag=1286957',
'order_reply4={order_tag=1286958',
'order_reply5={order_tag=1286959',
'order_reply6={order_tag=1286960',
'order_reply7={order_tag=1286961',
);

s/.*order_tag=// for @list;
# @list now contains only the tag values
print join("\n",@list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*order_tag=//' YourFile
# -> 1286961

sed 's/.*\(order_tag=\)/\1/' YourFile
# -> order_tag=1286961
```

Answer (score 0):

grep is the right tool:

```
kent$  grep -Po '.*order_tag=\K.*' f
1286955
1286956
1286957
1286958
1286959
1286960
1286961
```

Answer (score 0):

On the way out the door but, here's another way with split on the = character:

```
perl -e '$o=q(order_reply1={order_tag=1286955); $n=(split /=/, $o)[-1]; print "o= $o\n"'
```